# What do you call something that is in parity or quasi-parity?

Tags: word-request

For example, I want to say "Male/Female parity", but I also want to cover cases where there are slightly more male or female (35vs49), but saying "Male/Female parity or quasi-parity" is way too long-winded. Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe "approximate gender parity", or "near gender parity". Presumably the context is established such that you don't need to specify "gender numerical parity".